# Search on specific users in the table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE id NOT 
IN (

SELECT user_id
FROM  `bids` 
WHERE DATE_SUB(  DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 7 
DAY ) , INTERVAL 14 
DAY ) <= created
)
AND id NOT 
IN (

SELECT user_id
FROM coupon_used WHERE code = 'ACTNOW'
)
AND id
IN (

SELECT user_id
FROM accounts
)
```

I just want to take specific users and search on them, instead of searching on all users in the table. Like I have the list of users with id 1,2,3,4,5 I only want to search on these users

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `WHERE` clause using `IN()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe using left outer joins will simplify your query and hopefully improve performance

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN bids on bids.user_id = users.id AND DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY), INTERVAL 14 DAY) <= bids.created
LEFT OUTER JOIN coupon_used on coupon_used.user_id = users.id AND coupon_used.code = 'ACTNOW'
INNER JOIN accounts on accounts.user_id = users.id
WHERE bids.id is null AND coupon_used.id is null
    AND users.id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```